# auto forward sender's email using mySQL to lookup up email address of recipient then send

Tags: mysql, messaging

Here is the scenario. Users of my web site can search for other users who live in the same vicinity. Match results display links which transfer match data to a send message page. The send msg page queries a mySQL database for the real email address of the matched user and substitutes it into the original email.

Is there a simple script to auto forward the original message to the real email address of the matched forum user without any human intervention.

If the site I'm starting gets busy I don't want to be tied up forwarding emails manually. I am totally new at this and don't know the necessary steps or components to accomplish this. I do know some javascript, php, asp etc. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There is no way for MySQL to launch an external process (such as mail).  You could write a program that checks the database periodically for things to forward and do the forwarding.

Comment: Thanks Rick. When the user clicks "send message" it triggers a php script that retrieves the correct address from the database then executes a mailto: request... does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Where is the "send message button"?  Presumably in a PHP-generated HTML `<form> ... <input type=submit>Send Message ...`?  If you don't say otherwise, it goes back to the same PHP script.

Comment: form > script > database > script > (hidden) send mail page > confirmation page